# Clojure get local lets

Tags: clojure

How can you get a map of the local variables defined using let?

```
(let [foo 1] (println (get (get-thread-bindings) "foo")))
; prints nil
```

Is there another function that does this? Or is there a way to extract the variables from the get-thread-bindings map? Any solution should work with nested let statements as well.

Comment: Do you mean like this: http://blog.jayfields.com/2011/02/clojure-and.html ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As pointed out in the link in the comments, there's a special `&env` variable available inside `defmacro`. Per the [documentation](http://clojure.org/macros#Macros--Special%20variables):

> Two special variables are available inside defmacro for more advanced
>   usages:
>
> - &form - the actual form (as data) that is being invoked
> - &env - a map of local bindings at the point of macro expansion. The env map
>     is from symbols to objects holding compiler information about that
>     binding.

You can use this to write a macro that will expand to give you a mapping of local bindings at the point where the macro is expanded:

```
(defmacro get-env
  []
  (into {} (for [k (keys &env)]
             [(name k) k])))
```

This expands as a map of symbol name `(name k)` to symbol `k` for all local bindings `(keys &env)` which, when evaluated, will give a map of symbol name to current binding for the symbol.

```
 user> (get-env) ; => {}
 user> (let [a 1] (get-env)) ; => {"a" 1}
 user> (let [a 1 b 2]
         (let [b 3 c 4] (get-env))) ; => {"c" 4, "b" 3, "a" 1}
```

It even works with function parameters:

```
 user> (defn foo [x] (let [y 1] (get-env)))
 user> (foo 2) ; => {"y" 1, "x" 2}
```

Comment: NB: In clojurescript you'll also end up with the function itself as a binding (inside a function that is).