# Cannot resolve local var in context

Tags: clojure

I got a context problem whit local vars in (seems to be) different contexts.

I like to create a special `fn`-alternave, where i can store the code non-evaluated. (in following code `my-fn`)

For my use case, i have to morph this code. I'll use the `morph`-macro for this, but my problem appears even without this.

```
; Should work like fn, but save the code of args and body
(defmacro my-fn 
  [args body]
      (with-meta  (list 'fn args body)
                  {:args (list 'quote args)
                   :body (list 'quote body) }))


; in this macro, the predicate should be morphed later. 
; Both args and body will be needed. 
; To show my problem, i will skip this morphing and return just the body 
(defmacro morph 
  [args body]
  body)
```

Now i pick some example data and create a predicate with `my-fn`.
While morphing and evaluating the new function, something happens that it cannot resolve the local vars inner the predicate.

```
; example data for this case
(def people  #{{:id "S1" :name "Smith" :status 20 } 
               {:id "S2" :name "Jones" :status 10 }
               {:id "S3" :name "Blake" :status 30 }})


(let [a 20
      f (my-fn [t] (<= a (:status t)))] ; pred should be used like fn 
  (let [pred (eval (list 'fn    ; later this second let code comes into a macro or somehting
                         (:args (meta f)) 
                         (list 'morph 
                               (:args (meta f)) 
                               (:body (meta f)))))]
  (filter pred people))) ; => clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: a in this context
```

Can someone explain, why this happens and how can i avoid this? When I a constant number instead of `a` in the definition of `f`, everything works fine. But this dows not help in my usecase...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks for the explanation of local bindings.
For my use case, it is really important, that  I can use the `my-fn` just like `fn` (including use of local bindings).

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073530/clojure-get-local-lets) for accessing local bindings in a macro.

So i store the local environment in `my-fn` and put a `let` around the morphed predicate with all local bindings from above (in a later version just the bindings that are needed) and the predicate words fine.

So my new version of the functions and macros look like this:

```
(defmacro my-fn
  [args body]
      (with-meta  (list 'fn args body)
                  {:args (list 'quote args)
                   :body (list 'quote body)
                   :env (list 'get-env)}))

(defmacro morph
  [args body]
  body)


; example data for this case
(def people  #{{:id "S1" :name "Smith" :status 20 }
               {:id "S2" :name "Jones" :status 10 }
               {:id "S3" :name "Blake" :status 30 }})



 (let[a 20
      f (fn [t] (<= a (:status t)))]
   (filter f people))


 (defmacro get-env
  []
  (into {} (for [k (keys &env)]
             [(name k) k])))


(let [a 20
      f (my-fn [t] (<= a (:status t)))] ; pred should be used like fn
  (let [env (get-env)
        pred (eval (list 'fn    ; later this second let code for comes into a macro or somehting
                         (:args (meta f))
                         (list 'let
                               (reduce (fn[v [x y]] (conj v (read-string x) y)) [] (:env (meta f)))
                               (list 'morph
                                     (:args (meta f))
                                     (:body (meta f))))))]
   (filter pred people))) ; => ({:id "S3", :name "Blake", :status 30} {:id "S1", :name "Smith", :status 20})
```

Thx!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `eval` captures context, neither do the [docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/eval) state so.

```
; eval the context too
(eval '(let [a 3] a)) 
; => 3

; outer scope
(let [a 3] (eval 'a)) 
; => CompilerException .. Unable to resolve symbol: a in this context ..
```

EDIT:

> When I a constant number instead of a in the definition of f,
>   everything works fine.

Thats because `(= '3 3)` is true - a quoted number literal is its value. Whereas to even do anything with `a`s value you have to bind/resolve it (this is the point where `a` is simply not there/bound, but you try to use it).